# C# Code First Vs. SQL Database first when using a business logic layer

Tags: c#, sql, ef-code-first, database-first

I am firmly in the camp of being a database first developer. I believe there are pro's and cons' to each approach. However when creating a code first approach should the newly created classes have default values set?

E.g.

```
public DateTime DateCreated {get; set;} = DateTime.Now;
```

**If so what is the need for an existing business logic layer when the above property is not being referenced anywhere in the controller or business layer methods.**

Another point is the mere fact that if code first migrations are enabled on commented out code the column is dropped!

Data is precious.

Answer (score 0):

Business logic layer works as a medium from presentation layer and data access layer, so if a request in the business layer points to your property it gets fetched by data layer and returned

Comment: ,Exactly so. Why manipulate the code first classes if the property is not being used? It should be in the business logic layer

Comment: I don't really know to be honest, I never used code first approach. You should try to post the question on software engineering section, maybe they can give you more infos